# The code given is for rotation array for a given key

Tags: c

In the code given below,(say n=5) last two indices of array 'b'(that is b[4],b[5]) are showing garbage value.Why is it so?
sample i/p=[1 2 3 4 5],k=2
o/p=[3 4 5 1 2]

```
void main() {
    int i, j = 0, n, a[1000], b[1000], k, t, c = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);    // num of ele
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    scanf("%d", &k);    // key
    t = k;
    for(i = 0; i <= k; i++)
    { 
        b[i] = a[t];
        t++;
        c++;            // count
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    }
    for(i = c; i < n; i++)
    {
        while(j < k)   
        {
            b[i] = a[j];
            j++; 
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d", b[i]);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps time to use a debugger, as only you know what all the single-letter variables mean. One thing, what value is `j` supposed to at the start of the `while` loop? Not at the first iteration of the outer `for` loop, but next times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mixing two loops that either to the right thing or almost the right thing. Change:

```
for(i = c; i < n; i++)
{
    while(j < k)   
    {
        b[i] = a[j];
        j++; 
    }
}
```

to

```
for(i = c; i < n; i++)
{
        b[i] = a[j];
        j++; 
}
```

Or,

```
while(j < k)
{
    b[i] = a[j];
    j++;
    i++;
}
```

Your pick.

But, in the end, for this situation, I'd go for using `memcpy` for speed as in the example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *a = malloc(n * sizeof(*a));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    int *b = malloc(n * sizeof(*b));
    memcpy(b, &a[k], (n - k) * sizeof(*a));
    memcpy(&b[n - k], a, k * sizeof(*a));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d ", b[i]);
    free(b);
    free(a);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```